# Magento category tree is not shoing in category edit and product edit

Tags: magento

i am using magento 1.5 and have strange problem in the category edit and product edit page in 
admin, the subcategory tree for one category is not showing i have write the custom code to find the subcategory for that particular category and its not showing any subcategory using that code, but when i have checked in the database  all the subcategories for that particular category is available.

in simple words the subcategories tree for one category is not showing in category edit and product edit page in admin.

Thanks,
Jeet

Comment: check this site: http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-category-children-count-fix/ - the children_count query was what i needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can assure you that Zachary Schuessler solution works perfectly in 1.7.0.2.
I am just posting so it can help future questions.

1- I got this problem after i removed alot of products from a under Root category using "Catalog/Manage Categories" and deselecting the products in "Category Products" Tab.

2- The pattern category was **Hardware**, and inside i had several subcategories, the expand "+" sign just disappeared and as so all subcategories in backend, all fine in frontend.

3- Did as Zachary Schuessler said and looking at database at **Hardware** category ID, "children_count" column in "catalog_category_entity" i had a value of "-20".

4- Edited the value to "20" and all was fine again in backend.

Note: This also happened to me once when i moved a subcategory from one category and moved it inside other different category.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! You have saved me. It was the children count negative in my case as well.

Comment: Just ran into this issue using CE 1.9.4.3 and was also able to fix it like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Check your `children_count` column in `catalog_category_entity`. If you had the issue I did on 1.6, you probably have negative values there.

If that is the case, try this:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET children_count = "1" WHERE children_count < 0;
```

This didn't have any adverse effects when I used it months ago. Although, ideally you would want to calculate the `children_count` and set it correctly.

edit: I've also had the same issue with incorrect levels. If you imported all your products, it's possible the levels received incorrect values. If you have a sandbox setup, try this:

```
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category = $category->load($category->getId());

        $path = $category->getPath();

        $levels = explode('/', $path);

        if (is_array($levels) && count($levels)) {
            $category->setLevel(count($levels));
        }

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

        /**
         * Category save handler doesn't save level when using
         * the API. Use hard query instead.
         */
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $writeConnection->query('UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET level = ' . $category->getLevel() . ' WHERE entity_id = ' . $category->getId());
    }
```

Comment: @Jitendra - did you find a solution? Even if it is something else, you can add it as an answer and accept it. It helps others who come to this page get the solution.

Comment: Just ran into this issue using CE 1.9.4.3 and was also able to fix it like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an SQL statement to update all the children counts if they become out of sync from moving categories around. Had this issue occur for us when the server crashed halfway through moving a category inside another one.

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  parent_id, count(entity_id) totalChildren
       FROM    catalog_category_entity
      GROUP   BY parent_id) b ON a.entity_id=b.parent_id
SET a.children_count = b.totalChildren;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update these two queries

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET level =
(SELECT LENGTH(path)-LENGTH(REPLACE(path,'/','')) AS tmpl
FROM (SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity) AS table1
WHERE catalog_category_entity.entity_id = table1.entity_id);
```

and

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET children_count =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity) AS table2
WHERE path LIKE
CONCAT(catalog_category_entity.path,"/%"));
```